# What math operations does this abstraction of expression support?

Tags: haskell

A famous Haskell book has an exercise (spoiler alert) that asks to write functor, applicative and monad instances for a simplified data type of mathematical expressions. And no, this is not my homework for a course.

The following typechecks:

```
data Expr a = Var a | Val Int | Add (Expr a) (Expr a) deriving Show

instance Functor Expr where
  fmap f (Var x) = Var $ f x
  fmap f (Add e1 e2) = Add (fmap f e1) (fmap f e2)
  fmap _ (Val x) = Val x

instance Applicative Expr where
  pure x = Var x
  (Val x) <*> _ = Val x
  (Var f) <*> e = f <$> e
  (Add f g) <*> e = Add (f <*> e) (g <*> e)

instance Monad Expr where
  return = pure
  (Val x) >>= _ = Val x
  (Var x) >>= f = f x
  (Add e1 e2) >>= f = Add (e1 >>= f) (e2 >>= f)
```

However, the last part of the question asks to explain what bind does in this case, with an example. I think an even better question would be: what kinds of useful operations can you do with these abstractions? So I started to consider this, with the following expression:

```
expr :: Expr Char
expr = Add (Add (Var 'x') (Var 'y')) (Add (Var 'x') (Val 1))
```

The functor instance allows me to substitute a different name for a variable:

```
λ> (\v -> if v == 'x' then 't' else v) <$> expr
Add (Add (Var 't') (Var 'y')) (Add (Var 't') (Val 1))
```

But using it to substitute values for variables doesn't really seem to work:

```
λ> (\v -> if v == 'x' then 2 else 3) <$> expr
Add (Add (Var 2) (Var 3)) (Add (Var 2) (Val 1))
```

Here, however, the monad comes to the rescue:

```
λ> expr >>= (\v -> Val (if v == 'x' then 2 else 3))
Add (Add (Val 2) (Val 3)) (Add (Val 2) (Val 1))
```

With the help of the monad, it seems even possible to substitute expressions for a variable, here `t+2` is substituted for `x`:

```
λ> expr >>= (\v -> if v == 'x' then Add (Var 't') (Val 2) else pure v)
Add (Add (Add (Var 't') (Val 2)) (Var 'y')) (Add (Add (Var 't') (Val 2)) (Val 1))
```

But what else? What would be meaningful uses of the applicative? What other useful operations could we do with the monad?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The applicative instance corresponds to substituting for variables where the `Expr`-level structure of the substitution doesn't depend on the variable.  For example, if you were processing this expression in the context of a linear programming problem and wanted to replace each variable `Var 'x'` with a sum of two variables, one which is always positive and one which is always negative, you could write:

```
> import Control.Applicative
> expr <**> Add (Var (:"pos")) (Var (:"neg"))
Add (Add (Add (Var "xpos") (Var "xneg")) 
   (Add (Var "ypos") (Var "yneg"))) 
   (Add (Add (Var "xpos") (Var "xneg")) (Val 1))
>
```

The key here is that every variable is replaced with the same template `Add (Var "_pos") (Var "_neg")` where the new variables in the template have names that can depend on the original variable name.  That's what makes this operation applicative.

As an aside, note that substituting a `Val Int` for each `Var Char` isn't an applicative operation unless the *same* value is substituted for each variable -- the value of the `Int` is part of the `Expr`-level structure and can't depend on the variable name.

Because the monad instance can replace variables with an `Expr` that depends on the variable name, it can perform more general substitutions.

Ultimately, the Functor instance allows you to change variable names, the Monad instance allows you to substitute variables with arbitrary expressions, and the Applicative instance provides a limited sort of template substitution that just isn't very interesting or useful for this particular data structure.

That's really all they can do, though there is one generalization that you touched on with your failed attempt to use the Functor instance to substitute values.  These instances can change the type from `Expr Char` to some other `Expr b`.  For example, if you were compiling an expression to a bytecode that referenced variables by memory pointers, then suddenly variable "renaming" via the Functor becomes a little more interesting:

```
type Location = Int
symtab :: [(Char, Int)]
symtab = [('x', 4096), ('y', 4100)]  -- memory addresses

> fmap (fromJust . flip lookup symtab) expr
Add (Add (Var 4096) (Var 4100)) (Add (Var 4096) (Val 1))
>
```

Comment: I must admit I find it very surprising that these are all about substitution, which is the first thing that came to mind when considering the functor instance. It is possible to do all kinds of weird operations, such as Cartesian product -like `do { v1 <- expr; v2 <- expr; pure $ v1 : '_' : v2 : [] }`, but I failed to find a sensible mathematical application for these. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Substitution is pretty much what bind does, but that's a pretty useful tool. For instance you can make a function that eliminates all variables by lookups in an [(a,Int)] (and an extra Int as default value if the variable is not in the list).

I suppose the Monad instance could be made to do other stuff, for instance if it simplifies the expression when it rebuilds Add's (so Add (Val x) (Val y) is reduced to Val (x+y)), the function I mentioned above would always reduce the result to (Val n). Not sure you want to do that though.

The Applicative instance does not let you do anything you can not already do with the Monad instance (prove this by implementing <*> using >>= and pure).

Comment: Bind should not simplify, or the two identity laws (`return x >>= f = f x` and `m >>= return = m`) will not hold.

Comment: @DanielWagner That depends on how you define equivalence on expressions (although arguably if you have a simplifying bind you need to have a simplifying show). There are Monads where the laws only hold "morally", like the QuickCheck Gen monad.